# Tourist attractions on way from Stockholm to Oslo

Tags: sightseeing, scandinavia

I'll be going from Stockholm to Oslo by car. I understand the Oslojord area is very touristic. Are there any other nice attractions on this way? Somewhat off the direct route are Goethenburg and Uppsala, but I am not very familiar with the country. Charming ideas are very much appreciated.

Comment: Do not miss https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gothenburg_archipelago